# How to parse this simple json object in a for in loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, loops

```
var playlist = JSON.parse('{"VideoID" : {"VideoTitle" : "the title of the video"} }');

for(var video in playlist){
document.write(video + " "+ video.title +"<br>");
}
```

the output is : VideoID undefined

I want to the out put to be : VideoID the title of the video

Comment: `video` is a key, not value. There is no such property `title` in a String `video`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct usage is:

```
 for(var video in playlist){
    document.write(video + " "+ playlist[video].VideoTitle +"<br>");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
var playlist = JSON.parse('{"VideoID" : {"VideoTitle" : "the title of the video"} }');

document.write(playlist.VideoID.VideoTitle);
```